# Django initial data fixture installation order

Tags: python, django, fixtures, django-fixtures

My fixtures are loading in an incorrect order, so they fail to install - **app A** creates a model with a foreign key to a model in **app B**, but Django tries to load the initial data for **app B** first.

How can I control the order in which the initial data is installed?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the dirs for fixtures in settings.py `FIXTURE_DIRS`, but these are appended **after** the `fixtures` app directories. Thus you can rename `app_B/fixtures` to `app_B/slow_fixtures`, and add `app_B/slow_fixtures` to `FIXTURE_DIRS`.

[https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-FIXTURE_DIRS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-FIXTURE_DIRS)

Comment: Thanks, this will work. However, I feel it's sort of a hack... Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/management/commands/loaddata.py, method fixture_dirs. __Maybe__ Django loads the fixtures in the same order that `INSTALLED_APPS`, but I don't have time to dive in the code. Try to put app_A before app_B there.

Comment: @Dor, in https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/apps/registry.py you can see in `def populate()` that they use an OrderedDict to store the Apps in the same order that they are in  `INSTALLED_APPS`. In `def fixture_dirs()` the same Dict is used, so I assume the loading order of fixtures is the same as `INSTALLED_APPS`.